# Stored Procedure Union All issue

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, union-all

I have a stored procedure where I am trying to combine two different `SELECT` statements using `UNION ALL`, but after the query is executed only the items from the first `SELECT` are returned.

I wanted to get all items from both the first and second select statements.

Here is what I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report_AllActivitiesOfficesAll]
    @BeginDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS
    SET @BeginDate = .dbo.DateOnly(@BeginDate)
    SET @EndDate = .dbo.DateOnly(@EndDate)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
          O.OfficeId,
          O.OfficeName AS Name,
          AT.Description AS Activity,
          SUM(A.Duration) AS [Minutes], 
          CAST(SUM(A.Duration) AS FLOAT) / 60 AS [Hours],  
          COUNT(A.ActivityId) AS Activities,
          COUNT(DISTINCT A.CaseId) AS Cases,
          MIN(CAST(A.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) AS [Min Time],
          MAX(CAST(A.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) AS [Max Time],
          SUM(CAST(A.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) / COUNT(A.ActivityId) AS [Avg Time],
          SUM(CAST(A.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) AS [TotalHours]
      FROM Activity A
          INNER JOIN ActivityType AT ON A.ActivityTypeId = AT.ActivityTypeId
          INNER JOIN ActivityEntry AE ON A.ActivityEntryId = AE.ActivityEntryId
          INNER JOIN [Case] C ON A.CaseId = C.CaseId
          INNER JOIN [Office] O ON AE.OfficeId = O.OfficeId
          INNER JOIN [User] U ON C.CreatedByUserId = U.UserId
      WHERE .dbo.DateOnly(AE.ActivityDate) BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate 
      GROUP BY 
            O.OfficeId,
            O.OfficeName,
            AT.Description

      UNION ALL

      SELECT 
        O.OfficeId,
        O.OfficeId AS NonCaseOfficeId,
        O.OfficeName AS OfficeName,
        NCAT.Description AS NonCaseActivityType, 
        SUM(NCA.Duration) AS [Minutes],
        CAST(SUM(NCA.Duration) AS FLOAT) / 60 AS [Hours],
        COUNT(NCA.NonCaseActivityId) AS Activities,
        MIN(CAST(NCA.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) AS [Min Time],
        MAX(CAST(NCA.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) AS [Max Time],
        SUM(CAST(NCA.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) / COUNT(NCA.NonCaseActivityId) AS [Avg Time],
        SUM(CAST(NCA.Duration AS FLOAT) / 60) AS [TotalHours]
    FROM NonCaseActivity NCA
        INNER JOIN NonCaseActivityType NCAT ON NCA.NonCaseActivityTypeId = NCAT.NonCaseActivityTypeId
        INNER JOIN [Office] O ON NCA.OfficeId = O.OfficeId
        INNER JOIN [User] U ON NCA.UserId = U.UserId
    WHERE .dbo.DateOnly(NCA.ActivityDate) BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
    GROUP BY
        O.OfficeId,
        O.OfficeName,
        NCAT.Description
END
```

Comment: Post the whole stored procedure, must be something else wrong in there.

Comment: @Magnus I just added full code with recent changes.

Comment: You've got 11 columns each, but each column's datatype must be the same. You have a few columns that don't *appear* to be of same datatype.

Comment: Are you sure the 2'nd statement returns any values. You can view the queryplan to see if it is executed at all.

Comment: @Magnus - What i am trying to do is that for each office there is a bunch of activities that will be listed all grouped by office. Also each office has a bunch of noncase activities which also depend on office id. Since i was having trouble working with two different datasets in reportviewer i thought of making a stored procedure with all types of activities. Do you think i could possibly use a JOIN which will linked on the office id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns must match in data type and content to correctly and effectively use a union. You cannot change column names in the middle. If you need to know which part of the union a record came from add another column to do so. Yours do not. Officename is in the 2nd column in the first one and the third column in the second query. What is in the second column of the second query is highly likely not to be the same datatype as the second column of the first one.  This is not the only mismatch but an example.

If you need a column in the second query that you don't need in the first, you must still put it in the first query. And if you need a column in the first that you don't need in the second you must put a null value in that place in the query. For example (not a complete rewrite of what you have but enough to get an idea of what I am talking about):

```
SELECT            
    O.OfficeId,    
    CAST(NULL as int) as   NonCaseOfficeId     
    O.OfficeName AS Name,           
    AT.Description AS Activity, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT A.CaseId) AS Cases,
     cast('Case' as varchar (10)) as recordType         
FROM Activity A           
    INNER JOIN ActivityType AT ON A.ActivityTypeId = AT.ActivityTypeId           
    INNER JOIN ActivityEntry AE ON A.ActivityEntryId = AE.ActivityEntryId           
    INNER JOIN [Case] C ON A.CaseId = C.CaseId           
    INNER JOIN [Office] O ON AE.OfficeId = O.OfficeId          
    INNER JOIN [User] U ON C.CreatedByUserId = U.UserId       
WHERE .dbo.DateOnly(AE.ActivityDate) BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate        
GROUP BY              
    O.OfficeId,             
    O.OfficeName,             
    AT.Description   
UNION ALL        

SELECT          
    O.OfficeId,         
    O.OfficeId,         
    O.OfficeName,         
    NCAT.Description,
    cast(NULL as int),
     'NonCase'  
FROM NonCaseActivity NCA         
    INNER JOIN NonCaseActivityType NCAT 
        ON NCA.NonCaseActivityTypeId = NCAT.NonCaseActivityTypeId
    INNER JOIN [Office] O ON NCA.OfficeId = O.OfficeId         
    INNER JOIN [User] U ON NCA.UserId = U.UserId     
WHERE .dbo.DateOnly(NCA.ActivityDate) BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
```

Now since the query also takes the datatype from the first query, you  will see that I specifically cast it to the datatype I wanted.  You may need to do that on the null in the second part of the union as well just be sure that the datatypes are matching.  I believe null is assumed by SQL server to be an int if you don't specify, so this is most important when you want some other data type.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation i really appreciate it. But so i get myself clear - both select statements need to have the same datatype as well as naming?

Comment: @Amina, the datatypes need to match, but the names will use whatever was in the first query.

Comment: @KevinFairchild thanks for the tip the stored procedure is executing great but now i am getting all the case activities under the noncase activity column. All results from nonCase activity and case activity select statements are listed under noncase activity column names. How can i get so each select statement have their own set of column names? Thanks

Comment: You cannot have two sets of column names in one query in any database.

Comment: @HLGEM then how can i get two different stored procedures with different columns names to display in one? is there even such way? OR since both depend on office id could i do a joint with select statement in it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine to me. Keep in mind, the column names used will come from the first query.

So if I used a query like:

```
SELECT 1 AS Something
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS SomethingElse
```

I'd see just results (1 and 2) under a field called Something and wouldn't see anything for a field called SomethingElse.

Perhaps that's the issue?

Try adding an extra an extra field to both queries that identifies which resultset it's pulling from.

Maybe add 'Activity' AS Source for the first query and 'Non-Case Activity' AS Source for the second query, just to make sure you're getting a clear view of what's being shown?

Comment: Ok i will go ahead and give it a try and see. Thanks!

Comment: Tried this and it seems that all the items returned from this are the select items from the 1st select statement and nothing from the second.

Comment: Did you try running the second select directly?

Comment: @Amina, try running just the second query on its own.  Does it give you results?

Comment: @KevinFairchild Yes the second query worked because i tried each select statement in its own procedure and i got results back from it.